# Serving up cross origin HTML5 video requires bypassing OPTIONS preflight

Tags: html, apache, google-chrome, video, cors

I am attempting to serve up streaming video to an outside html5 video tag embedded in source that I have no control over. (The 3d virtual world, cloudparty).

In order for video assets to work at all, the video asset server must support CORS, and I have successfully done that for non-streaming assets. The problems arise with http streaming video. The encoder (VLC) knows nothing about CORS, so I must proxy the http stream it generates. Using mod_proxy, I am able to present the needed headers. I have added this to my virtual host in apache:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
# Mod_proxy Module
    ProxyReceiveBufferSize 16384

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyVia On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <LocationMatch "/vlcstreams">
        # VLC server stream
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8081
        #ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8081

        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin  "https://www.cloudparty.com"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET"
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Range, Accept-Encoding"
        Header set Accept-Ranges bytes
        #Header set Content-Length "-1"
    </LocationMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Now, if I use Firefox, all is good. The stream plays fine inside the 3D virtual world. However, when using Chrome, it insists on sending an OPTIONS preflight request to my server. My server responds with 501 - Not implemented. I am not sure if it is passing on the Options request to the VLC http server, or what it is doing. In any case, I need to reply with a 200 success no matter what. I have tried a few things with rewrite to respond to all options requests, but I just end up completely shutting down that virtual host.

If I start up Chrome in "insecure" mode, it also plays fine... so that would suggest it is definitely a cross domain security issue.

Is there a way for apache to respond to these OPTIONS preflight requests when proxying a stream like this?

Comment: I am looking for the same answer. I tried using mod rewrite and mod proxy and both seem to drop the preflight options request.